# Custom Exception Controller in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony4, php-7.2

I am building a custom exception controller in Symfony 4 to overwrite the `ExceptionController` class included in the Twig bundle.

I am doing this as per the [Symfony documentation for customizing error pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html).

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    exception_controller: App\Controller\Error::handleException
```

The reason I am using a custom exception controller is because I need to pass some additional variable to the template that are given by a custom `BaseController` class.

The Symfony docs mention the following about using a custom controller:

> The ExceptionListener class used by the TwigBundle as a listener of the kernel.exception event creates the request that will be dispatched to your controller. In addition, your controller will be passed two parameters:
>
> ```
> exception
>     A FlattenException instance created from the exception being handled.
>
> logger
>     A DebugLoggerInterface instance which may be null in some circumstances.
> ```

I need the `FlattenException` service to determine the error code but its not clear from the docs how these parameters are passed to the custom exception controller.

Here is my custom exception controller code:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;

class Error extends BaseController {

    protected $debug, // this is passed as a parameter from services.yaml
              $code;  // 404, 500, etc.

    public function __construct(BaseController $Base, bool $debug) {

        $this->debug = $debug;

        $this->data = $Base->data;

        // I'm instantiating this class explicitly here, but have tried autowiring and other variations that all give an error.
        $exception = new FlattenException();

        $this->code = $exception->getStatusCode(); // empty

    }

    public function handleException(){

        $template = 'error' . $this->code . '.html.twig';
        return new Response($this->renderView($template, $this->data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation page you are linking, at the very beginning of the chapter [Overriding the default template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates) the documentation actually cross link you to the class `\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController`, and this shows you how to use it.

So as per Symfony's own [ExceptionController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php#L55), the `FlattenException` is actually an argument of the action `showAction`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;    
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;

class Error extends BaseController {

    protected $debug; // this is passed as a parameter from services.yaml
    protected $code;  // 404, 500, etc.
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(BaseController $base, bool $debug) {

        $this->debug = $debug;

        $this->data = $base->data;

    }

    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null) {
        // dd($exception); // uncomment me to see the exception

        $template = 'error' . $exception-> getStatusCode() . '.html.twig';
        return new Response($this->renderView($template, $this->data));
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to also `use` `Request` & `DebugLoggerInterface` but this worked. Thank you!

Comment: oh, yes my bad, forgot to cross check your use statements and the `ExceptionController`'s ones, thanks for pointing out. Fixed in the answer